# how to grab all arguments besides the first one

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a meme creator in discord.js and to do that the person running the command must do something like this sr!memeuser @user meme text here,
because they must @ the user that is considered an argument, how would i get it to grab all of the arguments besides the first one, heres what ive tried:

```
let slicedArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
ctx.fillText(`${slicedArgs}`, 100, 350);
```

problem is, it still calls the first arg, please help!

Comment: can you give an example of what `arguments` looks like in your function?

Comment: Your code is correct. It has to be your assumption that isn't... Are you sure there isn't an extra first argument in `arguments` you didn't think would be there?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with `slice`. Here, I've used a "rest parameter" to collect all the arguments into an array called `args`.

```js
function logEverythingExceptFirst(...args) {
  // args is an array
  console.log(args.slice(1))
}

logEverythingExceptFirst('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
   

a = function(){
    var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    console.log(arg)
}

a(1,2,3)
a(1,2)
```